# Quicksort not working with little larger array size

Tags: ruby, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, quicksort

Below is my quicksort code in ruby, and its working fine for array size like 20-25 but getting either stack level too deep error or its getting stuck for longer time.

I am guessing i am doing a trivial mistake but not able to figure out.

```
  # This program is to do sorting using Quick sort.
require 'colorize'

class QuickSort
 attr_accessor :array
  def initialize(size)
   puts "Generating Random numbers for your array".cyan
   @array = (1..size.to_i).map do 
    rand(500) # Generating random numbers between 1 to 500.
   end
  # Boundary case
   if @array.size == 1
    puts  "Your sorted array is"
    p @array
    return
   end
   puts "Array Before Sorting".yellow
   p @array
   @head = 0
   @tail = @array.size-1
   startSort(@array,@head,@tail) #Start the searching logic.
  end

 # Quicksort logic
 def startSort(array,head,tail)
  if head < tail
   pivot = partitionArray(array,head,tail) # Calling the sorting logic  
   startSort(array,head,pivot-1)
   startSort(array,pivot+1,@tail)
  end 
 end


 # This method is called to partition the array based on pivot.
 def partitionArray(array,head,tail)
  pivot_value = array[(head+tail)/2] # Choosing random pivot value.
 # Run this partition step until head is equal to tail
  while head <= tail
    if array[head] < pivot_value
     head += 1
    elsif array[head] >= pivot_value
     if array[tail] > pivot_value
      tail -= 1
     elsif array[tail] <= pivot_value
      # Swapping head and tail values
      temp = array[head]
      array[head] = array[tail]
      array[tail] = temp
      # Moving each pointer forward from both the directions.
      head += 1
      tail -= 1
     end     
    end     
   end
   return head # Nothing but pivot
 end
end


 puts "Enter the size of Array"
 @size = gets.chomp
 # Checking if entry is a valid integer or not.
 if @size.match(/^(\d)+$/) 
  @obj = QuickSort.new(@size)
  puts "Array after sorting is ".green
  p @obj.array
 else
  puts "Invalid Entry".red
 end
```

Comment: Can you post the complete code please? I can't see where `@tail` is defined in the code you've posted.

Comment: hey @User089247 , i kept the whole code. can you also let me know how is my coding practise as well.

Comment: At least the last request would seem a better fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of quick sort algorithm is not correct. In a line:
`startSort(array, pivot + 1, @tail)`
you always call `startSort` method for `pivot + 1` and `array.size - 1` because `@tail` is an instance variable. It is assigned to `@array.size - 1` only once and its value never changes. However, simply changing this line to
`startSort(array, pivot + 1, tail)`
 is not enough to fix your code. With this change, it works fast even for large arrays but produces incorrect answer. This line should actually be:
`startSort(array, pivot, tail)`.
 With this change, it works fast for large arrays and sorts the array properly.